# opening a file where the filename is a stored variable

Tags: c++, input, stream

I have a class where I store a filename that a user has provided:

```
string EMNfn;               // IDF file EMN name

// IDF file EMN name
void CcaAna::put_EMNfn(string s)
{
    CcaAna::EMNfn = s;
}

string CcaAna::get_EMNfn()
{
    return EMNfn;
}
```

However, when I try to open the file, and I know it exists in the current directory that I am using with the following:

```
femn.open(cCCA.get_EMNfn());
```

I get a compile error C2664 ...cannot convert parameter 1 from 'class std::basic_string,class std::allocator >' to 'const char *'

When I try using:

```
femn.open(cCCA.get_EMNfn().c_str());
```

it compiles but trips my error code:

```
if(!femn)
{
    cout << "Open of Original EMN file failed\n";
    cout << "EMN file: " << cCCA.get_EMNfn() << endl;
    cout << "Press any key to exit" << endl;
    ch = getchar();
    return 1;
}
```

However when I type it in directly everthing works fine:

```
femn.open("262-003841-7-23.emn");
```

running out of ideas is there another way to open the stream?

**molbdnilo - I think you are on to something (see below)**

OK I added the two COUT lines after and I have included the OUTPUT below the code:

```
cout << "EMN file: " << cCCA.get_EMNfn() << endl;
//  THIS WORKS
//  femn.open("262-003841-7-23.emn");
    femn.open(cCCA.get_EMNfn().c_str());
//  femn.open(cCCA.get_EMNfn());

cout << "this works: " << "262-003841-7-23.emn" << endl;
cout << "*****" << cCCA.get_EMNfn() << "*****" << endl;
```

OUTPUT:
PROCESSING USER INPUT FILE ...
EMN file: "262-003841-7-23.emn"
this works: 262-003841-7-23.emn
*****"262-003841-7-23.emn"*****
Open of Original EMN file failed
EMN file: "262-003841-7-23.emn"
Press any key to exit

What I am seeing is that the stored string has " around it.  Is there a C++ way to remove those?

Comment: Are you certain that the strings are identical? Whitespace in particular can be very difficult to spot.

Comment: If you are launching your application with an IDE or debugger, the working directory may not be the same as the executable's location.

Comment: You should learn to use [references](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference). You are making a whole bunch of unnecessary copies of your strings.

Answer (score -1):

You are not assigning strings correctly!string variables  should not be assigned with `=` operator . [Here](http://cs.stmarys.ca/~porter/csc/ref/c_cpp_strings.html) is a reference for working with strings.

There are lots of ways for doing your task here is one:

`#include <string.h>
...
strcpy(CcaAna::EMNfn,s);//instead of CcaAna::EMNfn=s;`

maybe this might work,if not check the link and use a correct way to work with strings.

cheers

Comment: These are C++ `std::string`s, not C strings.

Comment: That link was very good but has me even more confused.  All my declarations are using C++ approach "string variable;"  and according to the link copying a string is C++ is as I have done it with the '=' sign.  It makes me believe it has something to do with the compile error I get when I use this approach: 'code' femn.open(cCCA.get_EMNfn()); 'code' 

I get a compile error C2664 ...cannot convert parameter 1 from 'class std::basic_string,class std::allocator >' to 'const char *'